# How is a statistics collection different to normal table stats?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, errors, statistics

I have a small table with few rows

```
create table dbo.p(i int);
insert dbo.p(i)
values (1), (2), (3), (4), (4);
```

I created statistics; no index, just the stats.

```
create statistics p_c on dbo.p(i) with fullscan;
```

I'm investigating various things so i tried to set the ROWCOUNT to the upper limit of a bigint.

```
update statistics dbo.p p_c with rowcount = 9223372036854775807;
```

This fails with error message

> Msg 3739, Level 11, State 3, Line 346
> Cannot UPDATE the index 'p_c' because it is not a statistics collection.

It also fails with `ROWCOUNT = 1;` although `update statistics dbo.p p_c` succeeds.

This error is not in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/errors-and-events-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017). I can find nothing online that seems relevant.

What is a statistics collection as opposed to plain-old table statistics? Why might setting ROWCOUNT be failing here?

SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU31-GDR) (KB5021126)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you update statistics and set `rowcount` or `pagecount` this updates partition level metadata rather than the statistics themselves.

This is shown when querying `sys.dm_db_partition_stats` and `sys.partitions` rather than the `Rows` returned by `DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS`.

For statistics not tied to an index there is no corresponding partition metadata to update.

As for "collection" - I assume it may be as the command will distribute the specified row count across the metadata of all the partitions in the table for that index.

i.e. For a table with four partitions setting `rowcount = 9223372036854775807` ended up with three partitions of `2305843009213693951` and one with `2305843009213693954` for me.